# Statement with limits of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have some statements with limits. We can have arbirary $a(n)$.
[image]

[image]

*First

$\implies$ if limit of $n*a(n)$ is zero, then $a(n)$ must be zero, because if we multiply something with no-zero value and it is still zero, then it must be zero. If limit of $a(n)$ is zero, then $a(n)$ is limited.

$\impliedby$ counter: $a(n)=1/n$ is limited, but $n*(1/n)$ is one, so it is not correct

*Second

$\implies$ counter: if we have limit of $((n)^{1/2})/n$, it is zero, but $(n)^{1/2}$ is not limited, so it is not correct

$\impliedby$ I am not quite sure about this one, dont know it is correct for all sequences, especially sin and so on, can you please explain?

*Third

Both are true, because if limit of $a(n)$ was $-1$, multiplied by $3$, it would have been $-1$, but it is $1$, so a(n) must be one

Thank you for your feedback and please give me hand especially with that second one "$\impliedby$".

Comment: If a seqeunce is limited, it does not necessarily mean that it has a limit, because sin(n*pi/2) is limited, but does not have a limit. If we do limit a(n)/n with this sequence we can use squeeze criterium, but I am not sure if it could be applied to all sequences. Would you be so kind and try to explain to me?

Comment: What does "limited" mean?

Comment: Where is this from? Could you please cite the reference?

Comment: Also need to say the sequences are real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\implies$: since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n=0$, the sequence $(n\cdot a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. Take $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\lvert n\cdot a_n\rvert<M$. Then $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\lvert a_n\rvert<\frac Mn\leqslant M$.; $\Longleftarrow$: you are right.
2. $\implies$: you are right; $\Longleftarrow$: Take $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\lvert a_n\rvert<M$. Then $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left\lvert\frac{a_n}n\right\rvert<\frac Mn$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n=0$.
3. Both are true because both maps $x\mapsto x^3$ and $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]x$ are continuous and map $1$ into $1$.

Answer (score 1):

All seem almost fine to me, for the second one $\impliedby$, if $a_n $ is limited that is $|a_n|\le M$ then

$$\left|\frac{a_n}n\right|=\frac M n \to 0$$

For the third one also we need a stronger argument, that is for example that both $a_n$ and $a_n^3$ are continuous bijection and $a_n=1\iff a_n^3=1$.

Comment: OK, so if any sequence is limited, it means that if we divide it by n->+inf, it is going to be zero, because we can find constant which is higher than absolute value of that sequence and constant divided by + infinity is zero, right?

Comment: We have that $\frac M n =M\cdot \frac1n \to M\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: @naruto25 The expression "a constant divided by infinity is zero" is not the proper way to express the concept, we should state "a constant divided by n, which tends to infinity, tends to zero".